# How do i print a table in C without having to move the vertical lines?

Tags: c

I  have to shift the vertical lines like this because the output displays misaligned lines.

```
    printf("DAY 10                           DAILY SUMMARY REPORT                             ");
    printf("\n+---------------------+--------------++-------------+-------------+------------+");
    printf("\n| Today's             | Total        || Total       | Total       | Under      |");
    printf("\n| Cases               | Cases        || Deaths      | Recovered   | treatment  |");
    printf("\n+---------------------+--------------++-------------+-------------+------------+");
    printf("\nLocal :   %d           |              ||             |             |            |",day10localcase);
    printf("\nImported :%d           |              ||             |             |            |", day10importcase);
    printf("\n          %d          |%d           ||%d            |%d           |%d          |", day10case,day10casetotal,day10deathtotal,day10rectotal,day10treattotal);
    printf("\n+------------------------------------++-------------+-------------+------------+");
    printf("\n                                     ||%.1lf%%         |%.1lf%%        |%.1lf%%       |",day10deathtotalpercent,day10rectotalpercent,day10treattotalpercent);
    printf("\n                                     ++----------------------------------------+");
    printf("\n----------------------------End of Day 10 Reporting-----------------------------");
}
```

Comment: You probably want to add a width specifier: For example `"%10d"`.

Comment: Are you using monospace fonts to see the output?

Comment: I wrote a lot of reports like this early in my career. My feelings are a odd combination of nostalgia and PTSD.

Comment: Maybe try using some tabulations by using \t ?

Comment: Did you consider determining the width of the values you output and then calculate the value you need for the width specifier as mentioned by Johnny Mop?

Comment: @Darkpingouin In my experience that at first gives exilerating results and much later turns out to have nasty hidden effort surprises...

Comment: In addition to the width specifier as mentioned by @JohnnyMopp, you might also want a `-` flag if you want the output to be left-justified within the field width instead of the default right-justified output.